# Simulating Load for a new (Windows) Environment

Tags: windows-server-2008

Is there a tool or a bunch of scripts which are be able to generate some user/client like load for a complete Windows server environment? I'm talking terminal services, exchange usage, log-ons/offs, general file usage? I'm in the middle of the planing phase of a new Windows domain (and new HW!) and basically want to see how the new stuff will be handling the users. Doesn't have to be anything fancy, just plain simple and dumb. I'm very well aware that this isn't a simple thing to do and that a lot of factors have to be considered quite carefully when one wants to talk about how many users a certain configuration is able to handle. Suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load test your terminal server setup you can use [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/rds/archive/2009/10/30/remote-desktop-load-simulation-toolset.aspx)